# Find the voltage source in the circuit

Tags: voltage

Given \$v_2 = 600 i_2\$ and \$i_2 = 2\,\textrm{mA}\$, determine \$v_s\$ in mV.

[image]

I know that \$i_2 = -9 * v_1\$.

I know how to find \$v_1 = -\frac{600}{9}\,\textrm{mV} = -66.66\,\textrm{mV}\$.

I am not sure how to find \$v_s\$, but I know that I need to use the current of the right loop.

Comment: Where's the second connection between the loops that would allow current to flow between them?

Comment: i'm not sure, that is the way the problem was presented to me

Comment: So then no current flows. This is purely a math problem.

Comment: does that mean its 0?

Comment: No, that means that the difference between v_1 and v_s is 0.

Comment: so the voltage source would be the same as v_1...meaning its -66.66mV

Answer (score 1):

```
Given i2 = 2mA;
hence 9V1 = -2mA
hence V1 = 2mA/9 = - 0.2222v
sine Source Vs is parallel to the input impedance shown
Vs = - 0.2222v
```

so **`Vs = - 0.2222v`**

Answer (score 0):

> I know that \$i_2 = −9 \cdot v_1\$

Yes.

> I know how to find \$v_1 = −600/9 = −66.66mV\$

No, that does not follow. If you solve the first equation for v1, you get

\$v_1 = i_2 / -9\$

since you know that \$i_2\$ is 2 mA, that makes \$v_1 = -0.222 mV.\$

Comment: ok. and since there is no potential difference in the voltages, v_s = -0.222mV, am i correct?